# How to add custome label for html code which is in static resources

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

How to add custome label for cancel button in below html code which is in static resources

```
$j('#progressBox').append(fileName + '<div class="progress"><div id="' + progressBarId + '" class="bar progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"></div></div><div><a href="#" id="'+cancelId+'">Cancel</a><div>Size:'+size+' KB<br/><br/>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following approach - just define script variable on visualforce page and use it in your static resource script.

Updated script:

```
$j('#progressBox').append(fileName + '<div class="progress"><div id="' + progressBarId + '" class="bar progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"></div></div><div><a href="#" id="'+cancelId+'">' + cancelLabel +'</a><div>Size:'+size+' KB<br/><br/>');
```

VF page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cancelLabel = "{!$Label.Cancel}"
</script>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.updatedScript}"/>
```

So you may just define a variable with all labels you want to use on the vf page and successfully use them in script.

```
// vf page initialization    
var labels = {
    cancel : "{!$Label.Cancel}",
    save : "{!$Label.Save}",
    anyOtherLabel : "{!$Label.AnyOtherLabel}"
}

// static resource using
$j('#progressBox').append(fileName + '<div class="progress"><div id="' + progressBarId + '" class="bar progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"></div></div><div><a href="#" id="'+cancelId+'">' + labels.cancel +'</a><div>Size:'+size+' KB<br/><br/>');
```

Comment: how can i add custome label in static resource  js alert